# Handling spaces in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

One of the external libraries that my app uses have spaces in its logcat tag:

```
Log.d("Some External Library", "Debug Message");
```

How do I write the filter-spec in the logcat command to handle spaces? Logcat inside eclipse was able to filter it but I prefer the command line.

I've tried the following and they don't work:

```
adb logcat -s "Some External Library"
adb logcat -s Some\ External\ Library
adb logcat -s Some External Library
```

Comment: adb logcat|grep "Some External Library"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So my advice would be to use an pipe. Write:

```
adb logcat | grep 'Some External Library'
```

Maybe someone else has another idea.

If you need only debug messages write `adb logcat '*:D' | grep 'Some External Library'` for more possible tags write `adb logcat --help`

The problem with this is, you can't use this solution in an `adb shell` environment, because the file-system there is read-only. But this solution should give you more or less the results you want.

Commands like *adb logcat -s 'Some External Library'* or *`logcat -s '"Some External Library":D'`*  are not working.

Comment: I recommend you edit this answer so that the use of grep comes earlier